# Unix Executable unable to execute in MAC OSX

Tags: java, macos, terminal, processbuilder

I have a console application written in C++ (using boost libraries) and compiled in xcode , This unix executable  communicates with a daemon and do a specific task. 
when I run this console application from command line with all arguments it works perfectly.
But when I call this console application from Java code its not executing.
I am using `ProcessBuilder` to execute it. Am able to execute system related command using the same code. The console application what I am using depends on static library.

Following are the spec's am using:
Jdk - 1.7,
Mac OSX - 10.7.5,
XCode - 4.6.2,
Boost version - 1.53.0.

Code I am using:

```
String str[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c" ,"/Users/user/Downloads/cppapplication_1"};
           ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(str);
       builder.directory(new File("/Users/user/Downloads/")); 
        final Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Its not throwing any error. Its hanging.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the precise command you are using?  Sample code of how you are using `ProcessBuilder`.  What exceptions are you getting?  Given the fact that we can not actually run the command our selves, you've going to have to provide much more information about your problem then that for use to even be remotely be able to help you.

Comment: Be sure to consume the error stream as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [execute system processes with Java ProcessBuilder and Process](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-3)

Definitely this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `Open System call`.

you can use `String str[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "open -a Terminal /Users/user/Downloads/cppapplication_1"};`

I dont know the exact reason why it worked with `open system call`,once I was also facing same issue, third party unix executable was working fine from command line but not with java code. when calling from java code Process was not terminating also not generating any output to stout.
 That time `Open system call` worked for me, the only problem was it was launching a new terminal window. I managed it with `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "'Terminal'" to false'` to hide terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but I had this exact same issue with a unix executable on osX, last day. Made me pull out a fair bit of hair.

Finally this worked for me:

```
*

    proc = builder.start();
    OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
    out.close(); //This part is the key


     BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new          InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    //proceed to read from the buffered reader etc.
```

*

I had to manually close the outputstream as explained above. It seemed the outputStream was waiting for some sort of input when there was actually none.

So in my case anyway, closing the outputstream did the trick and the exec is working as expected now. Any input on why the process was waiting for an input when there was none (unrecognizable EOL?), could be helpful.